# Remote Connection Failed connecting to Git repo

Tags: git, ssh-keys, assembla, git-tower

EDIT: This is solved now but I don't have enough rep to answer it just yet.

I have a local git repository that I want to host on assembla.com. I'm using Git Tower, and I generated a keypair using

```
ssh-keygen -C xyz@gmail.com
```

(The gmail address is my registered email on assembla and tower)

I uploaded my public key to assembla which seemed to work, then on Git Tower I select my project, go to Settings > Remotes and enter a custom name for the project, then enter the repository URL as stated on my assembla project page:

```
git@git.assembla.com:abc.git
```

I select private Key and choose the private key generated with the above command. Tower automatically completes the username field (as "git") from the repository URL. I enter the Key Password the same as when I generated the key pair from command line and when I click add and get the following error.

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I checked similar questions but I'm not having any luck. It seems to be an error authenticating, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Assembla took a LONG time to register the keys. I tried again with the same keys a few days later and it worked.

Comment: How long did it take ?

Comment: Sorry I was away for a week. I'm not sure exactly but I left it until the next day. Maximum 24 hours I think.